# Seeking algorithm behind End Point Rate (EPR) to calculate movement of shoreline over period of years?

Tags: algorithm, shoreline

I am analyzing the shoreline change over a period of 20 years(1998-2018). I have following data:

1. digitized shorelines of 1998, 2003,2008,2013 and 2018
2. one common baseline for all shorelines
3. transect lines from baseline to shorelines.
4. I have the lat/long of the intersection points of transect lines and
   shorelines.
5. The distance between shoreline and baseline from the intersection
   point.

I need to calculate the EPR (End point rate) and NSM (net shoreline movement).
My [DSAS Tool is not working due to some .dll file missing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274181/mclmcrrt78-dll-error-while-calculating-statistics-for-transects-of-shorelines).
I need to figure out the algorithm behind these calculations. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: If you are seeking an algorithm then what relevance does ArcGIS Desktop have to your question beyond displaying your input data?

Comment: DSAS Tool is not working due to mclmcrrt78.dll file missing. I am not able to resolve the issue so I thought of moving on and try other alternative.

Comment: Have you tried searching Google for `algorithm "end point rate"`, or `arcgis "end point rate"` if you think the solution may lay there?

Comment: We see DSAS questions occasionally (https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=dsas) so perhaps where you are stuck with that may be a separate question that you can ask.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274181/mclmcrrt78-dll-error-while-calculating-statistics-for-transects-of-shorelines
Yes i already did put a question.
I am searching on google too and read many articles regarding the same. I have not got clarity on my doubt. Any information from any medium would be helpful to me.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Have you contacted the Woods Hole Coastal and Marine Science Center to see if they recognize your DLL error and/or would be willing to share the algorithm that they use with you?

Comment: I have not contacted Woods Hole Coastal and Marine Science Center yet. I will take that approach as suggested by you and will update the outcome of that. Thanks for suggestions.